# How come default vars are not visible to Ansible molecule Verify?

Tags: ansible, molecule

I have this a role with a `defaults/main.yml` which defines these vars:

```yaml
# Ansible deployment vars
archive_audio_etc_dir: "/etc/archive/audio"
archive_audio_log_dir: "/var/log/archive/audio"
... other stuff ...
```

and this role has this `tasks/main.yml`

```yaml
- name: Archive Audio | Create directories
  ansible.builtin.file:
    path: "{{ item }}"
    state: directory
    owner: root
    group: root
    mode: 0755
  with_items:
    - "{{ archive_audio_etc_dir }}"
    - "{{ archive_audio_log_dir }}"
```

This role also has a `molecule/default/verify.yml` file:

```yaml
---
# This is an example playbook to execute Ansible tests.

- name: Verify
  hosts: all
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:

  - name: Check Created directories
    ansible.builtin.stat:
      path: "{{ item }}"
    with_items:
      - "{{ archive_audio_etc_dir }}"
      - "{{ archive_audio_log_dir }}"
    register: dir_stats
```

When I run `molecule test` the Verify play fails with this error:

```
PLAY [Verify] ******************************************************************

TASK [Check Created directories] ***********************************************
fatal: [centos7]: FAILED! => {"msg": "'archive_audio_etc_dir' is undefined"}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
centos7                    : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Why is `archive_audio_etc_dir` undefined in the Verify play?

UPDATE:

I have updated my verify.yml after reading the docs as suggested.
Here is my new version:

```yaml
---
# This is an example playbook to execute Ansible tests.

- name: Verify
  hosts: all
  become: true
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:

  # we do this so the Verify playbook can have access
  # to default vars.  See:
  # https://molecule.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting-started.html#the-scenario-layout

  - name: Initialize role without actually running it
    ansible.builtin.include_role:
      name: audio
      tasks_from: init

  - name: Check Created directories
    ansible.builtin.stat:
      path: "{{ item }}"
    with_items:
      - "{{ archive_audio_etc_dir }}"
      - "{{ archive_audio_log_dir }}"
    register: dir_stats
```

I also added an empty file `tasks/init.yml` to the role.  But I still get the same error when the `Verify` play runs:

```
PLAY [Verify] ******************************************************************

TASK [Initialize role without actually running it] *****************************

TASK [Check Created directories] ***********************************************
fatal: [centos7]: FAILED! => {"msg": "'archive_audio_etc_dir' is undefined"}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
centos7                    : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: _verify.yml_ is not part of the role, it is just a playbook launched where you can use Ansible to assert the result of the launched role. Hence it does not inherit the variables from the role.

Comment: This is kind-of implicitly stated in the note here: https://molecule.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting-started.html#the-scenario-layout > _If the `verify.yml` playbook does not explicitly `include_role` your role, the library and `module_utils` provided by your role are not available in the playbook by default._; and so this also goes for the variables.

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε Thanks for pointing me to the docs.  They make sense, well at least, I thought they did.  Please see my update to my OP.  Thank you.

Comment: You were almost there, only a bit more reading on the `include_role` module this time. You need to set [`public: true`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/include_role_module.html#parameter-public) for role's `vars` and `defaults` to be exposed to the playbook.

Comment: Ah! Thanks that got me to the ol' `sudo not found` error so I added this line `  become_method: su` to my verify.yml.

Answer (score 0):

You can manually include default variables using the [ansible.builtin.include_vars module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/include_vars_module.html).

Here is how you might include the defaults in a Molecule verify.yml file:

```yaml
- name: Include default vars
  ansible.builtin.include_vars:
    dir: '{{ lookup("env", "MOLECULE_PROJECT_DIRECTORY") }}/defaults/'
    extensions:
      - 'yml'
```